# very basic python code. Trying to find out if each word in lst is alphabetical based on its initial, middle, and final letters. Why do i get errors?

Tags: python, list

I've done everything I can but I keep getting a bunch of errors. How can I fix them in order for the code to print out the alphabetically sorted words.

```
def alphabeticalcount(example):


    lst = example.split()
    for wrd in lst:
        srortedword = ""
        if len(wrd) // 2 == 0:
            initial = lst[0]
            middle = lst[len(wrd) // 2]
            final = lst[-1]
        else:
            initial = wrd[0]
            middle = wrd[len(wrd) // 2] 
            final = wrd[-1]

        wrdsum = inital + middle + final
        wrdsort = sorted(wrdsum)
    
print(alphabeticalcount("red cat abc dog hat"))
```

Comment: You have a typo in the variable name `initial` on this line: `wrdsum = inital + middle + final`

Comment: @John Kay `x = "red cat abc dog hat"` then convert it to a list `y = x.split(" ") ` after that sort it with this `y.sort()`

Comment: can you confirm that `abc` is "alphabetical" and the `cat` is not "alphabetical" ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the words alphabetically, you can use the `sort` or `sorted` functions.
The difference between them is that `sort` changes on the original list and `sorted()` makes a new list.

So the function would look like this:

```py
def alphabeticalcount(words):
    w = words.split(' ')
    x = sorted(w)

    return x

words = "red cat abc dog hat"

result = alphabeticalcount(words)
print(result)
```

and the result would be this:

```
['abc', 'cat', 'dog', 'hat', 'red']
```

If the question refers to "is each word alpahbetical based on the order of its own letters", then would would do this:

```py
def alphabeticalcount(words):
    words= words.split(' ')
    
    alphabetical = []
    for w in words:
        if w[0] < w[1] and w[1] < w[2]:
            alphabetical.append(True)
        else:
            alphabetical.append(False)

    return alphabetical

words = "red cat abc dog hat"

result = alphabeticalcount(words)
print(result)
```

which would return this:

```
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

(because only "abc" is "alphabetical").